# How can I force my web service to accept a different prefix?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asmx

I'm creating a .asmx endpoint so a third party can send me a soap request. 
The third party example looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://catmanager.com/schemas/catmanager/v8.8.2/notify">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tns:notifyCatExtendedStatusChange xmlns:tns="http://catmanager.com/schemas/catmanager/v8.8.0/notify">
         <CatJob>
            <not:CatCode>FTC</not:CatCode>
            <not:ClientStatus>URGENT</not:ClientStatus>
         </CatJob>
      </not:notifyCatExtendedStatusChange>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I create a SOAPUI project using the wsdl from my service, my xml is expecting this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:not="http://catmanager.com/schemas/catmanager/v8.8.2/notify">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <not:notifyCatExtendedStatusChange>
         <CatJob>
            <not:CatCode>Bernard</not:CatCode>
            <not:ClientStatus>NOT URGENT</not:ClientStatus>
         </CatJob>
      </not:notifyCatExtendedStatusChange>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need my service to accept requests with **tns** instead of **not**.

I think I need to force the prefix, but I can't work out how to do this. 
I've found this link, which looks very complicated, but I'll try it next if there isn't an easier method:
http://benscoderepo.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/adding-soap-prefix-to-asmx-service.html

Here's my asmx code:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Description;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace CatApp
{

    [WebService(Namespace = "http://catmanager.com/schemas/catmanager/v8.8.2/notify")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]

    public class CatService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        [SoapRpcMethod("urn:notifyCatExtendedStatusChange",RequestNamespace = "http://catmanager.com/schemas/catmanager/v8.8.2/notify", ResponseNamespace = "http://catmanager.com/schemas/catmanager/v8.8.2/notify", Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal)]

        [return: XmlElement("UpdateCatExtendedStatusResponse")]
        public string notifyCatExtendedStatusChange(catJob CatJob)
        {
            return CatJob.ClientStatus;
        }
    }


    public class catJob
    {
        public string CatCode { get; set; }
        public string ClientStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class updateCatExtendedStatusResponse
    {

        private int idField;

        private bool statusUpdatedField;


        [XmlElementAttribute(Form = global::System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.idField = value;
            }
        }

        [XmlElementAttribute(Form = global::System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public bool StatusUpdated
        {
            get
            {
                return this.statusUpdatedField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.statusUpdatedField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I changed

```
Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal
```

to

```
Use = SoapBindingUse.Default
```

It started working with the third party example. I switched it back to Literal and it still works. I'm mystified, but I'm glad everything has started working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not the prefix. The problem was that the 3rd party was accidentally sending the wrong name space:

http://catmanager.com/schemas/catmanager/v8.8.**0**/notify